# How to get specific logs in controller

Tags: appdynamics

I have deployed analytics-agent with machine agent in a server and configured pattern to grok logs of application. I'm able to see logs in Controller UI. I want to send only level=ERROR logs to controller. How can this be achieved?

Job file

```
version: 2
enabled: true
source:
    type: file
    path: /data/nifi/logs
    nameGlob: nifi-app.log
    startAtEnd: true

fields:
   sourceType: nifi

grok:
  patterns:
    - '%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:level} \[%{DATA:thread}\] %{DATA:class} %{GREEDYDATA:message}'

eventTimestamp:
   pattern: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"
```

Log Sample

```
2019-05-20 17:59:31,409 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-22] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.ListSFTP ListSFTP[id=282914ca-f485-32ff-8ba9-93236a9de836] Failed to perform listing on remote host due to java.io.IOException: Failed to obtain connection to remote host due to com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about getting the level as a field, then try this grok pattern which only matched the ERROR lines.

> %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} ERROR [%{DATA:thread}] %{DATA:class}
>   %{GREEDYDATA:message}